# Google Sheets Using Named Range in Query statement doesnt work

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, named-ranges

i have a question regarding the query statement using a named range in Google Sheet.

I have some cells which i gave a named range like R3_3

now i can query this named range in the selected Data

```
=QUERY({R3_3},"Select * ")

with these results (expected results)

-0.04
205.00
-0.09
-0.10
-0.11
```

Its only one column so i can filter it for example by values greater 100, it works fine with this statement

```
=QUERY({R3_3},"Select * where Col1 > 100 ")

with these results

205.00
```

**How can i use a Named Range in the query statement itself, so i tell the query to regard the named range (array or single column) and filter it by some statement like if entries in the named range are greater than 100?**

```
Like that:

=QUERY({R3_3},"Select * where "&R3_3 > 100 ")

-> It shows me "Formula Parse Error"
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY({NamedRange1}, "where Col1 > 100")
```

[image: 0]

and if you have multi-column named range (for example A:B) you can just do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in query(), but maybe you'd want to use filter() ?

```
=filter(R3_3, R3_3>100)
```

Comment: Ist it possible to then to query a Column where the column should contain several entries of a named range? And show only the entries of the query if there is a match in the column with the named range?

Comment: `=QUERY('Master Eingabe'!A:M,"Select * Where H = 'Luzerner Zeitung' AND I contains "&{Luzerner}& ")`

Comment: Is the column to query part of the named range?

Comment: Yea, it would be

Comment: set up some filter but would be more cool if possible directly in query